# Como usar un HashMap con dos Keys?

Tags: java, hashmap

Necesito crear un HashMap cuya forma de acceso sea la combinación de dos llaves.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: y cual seria el problema?? que puede contener un hashmap?

Answer (score 1):

Hay muchas formas de llevarlo a cabo, un par de ellas recomendadas serían:

**Doble Mapa**

```
Map<String, Map<String, Object>> doubleKeyMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String,Object>>();

// Agregar valores

doubleKeyMap.put("key1A", new HashMap<String, Object>(){{put("key2A", "Test");}});
doubleKeyMap.put("key1B", new HashMap<String, Object>(){{put("key2B", 123);}});
doubleKeyMap.put("key1C", new HashMap<String, Object>(){{put("key2C", false);}});

// Leer valores

doubleKeyMap.get("key1A").get("key2A"); // Test (String)
doubleKeyMap.get("key1B").get("key2B"); // 123 (int)
doubleKeyMap.get("key1C").get("key1C"); // false (boolean)
doubleKeyMap.get("key1A").get("key2B"); // null (No existe la combinación de keys)
```

**Key Wrapper**

```
public class Key {

    private final String k1;
    private final String k2;

    public Key(String k1, String k2) {
        this.k1 = k1;
        this.k2 = k2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Key)) return false;
        Key key = (Key) o;
        return k1.equals(key.k1) && k2.equals(key.k2);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return k1.hashCode()+k2.hashCode();
    }

}

Map<Key, Object> keyWrapperMap = new HashMap<Key, Object>();

// Agregar valores

keyWrapperMap.put(new Key("key1A", "key2A"), "Test");
keyWrapperMap.put(new Key("key1B", "key2B"), 123);
keyWrapperMap.put(new Key("key1C", "key2C"), false);

// Leer valores

keyWrapperMap.get(new Key("key1A","key2A")); // Test (String)
keyWrapperMap.get(new Key("key1B","key2B")); // 123 (int)
keyWrapperMap.get(new Key("key1C","key2C")); // false (boolean)
keyWrapperMap.get(new Key("key1A","key2B")); // null (No existe la combinación de keys)
```

Answer (score -2):

Puedes hacer una concatenación de tus 2 valores

```
Map<String, Object> mapa = new HashMap<>();
mapa.put("llave1" + "_" + "llave2", objeto);
```

De lo contrario utiliza un mapa donde la llave sea un objeto con 2 atributos que sean tus llaves

```
public class Key{
    private String key1;
    private String key2;
    public Key( String k1, String k2){
        key1 = k1;
        key2 = k2;
    }
}
```

Y en el código usarla algo así

```
Map<Key, Object> mapa = new HashMap<>();
mapa.put(new Key("llave1", "llave2"), objeto);
```

Comment: Lo de concatenar claves puede llevar a error. Por ejemplo: {"clave","uno"} y {"cla","veuno"} darían el mismo resultado. La segunda solución sí que sería la correcta.

Comment: Correcto estimado Pablo, ya está editado, con un carácter de separación se soluciona lo que comentabas